# Get active parent line item with menu to be white

Tags: css

JS Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/97oqg2vd/7/):

I'd like the active, as well as hovered text items to have white text. Right now only the hovered items behave as desired. So I tried adding:

```
 .dropdown > ul li a:hover, .dropdown ul li.current_page_item a {
  color: white;}
```

I expected to see the active menu item have orange text, as well as hovered ones. But it looks like adding this effects unhovered drop down line items too. How can I isolate to exclude this effect?

For example, if you add the above snippet of CSS to the js fiddle and hit run, look what happens to the drop down menu. Screen shot here:

[image]

Those items in the drop down should not have white text, that styling was only meant to affect hovered and active menu items.

How can I add CSS to make it so that only active and hovered items have white text (To contrast against the orange background that goes along with them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of isolating the styling using the [direct child combinator, `>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators).

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/haLsz2c6/)

```
.dropdown ul li.current_page_item > a,
.dropdown > ul li > a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```

And if you want the text to change color when hovering over the entire `li` element, use the selector:

```
.dropdown > ul li:hover > a
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/t7h2m8pz/)

Comment: Thank you very much I'd been really spinning my wheels there. Also thanks for the tip on moving the hover state to the li item and not the anchor item, thereby getting "the entire" li. I'd always thought that the state (hover, active, etc) could only go on the last component of a selector. I had no reason to think that other than that's the only way I've seen it used till now. Thanks again